# Using pytest fixture with asynctest

Tags: python, testing, python-asyncio

I am using [asynctest](https://asynctest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and I want to leverage pytest fixture. I'm intersted by (but not only) the [**caplog** fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html#caplog-fixture).

In an asynctest testing class, I can use `with self.assertLogs():` but this is not sufficient when my logs are not produced within the block.

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import asynctest


async def worker():
    logging.error(":(")


class TestClass(asynctest.TestCase):
    """Testing class. """

    async def setUp(self):
        self.worker_task = asyncio.ensure_future(worker())

    async def tearDown(self):
        try:
            self.worker_task.cancel()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass

    async def test_get_error_log(self):
        """ Simple test that assert logs emitted. """
        with self.assertLogs(level="ERROR") as cm:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

The test above if failing but if I have:

```
---------- Captured log call -----------
ERROR    root:tmp.py:7 :(
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact asynctest is build on top of [unittest](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/unittest.html) and has nothing in common with the pytest testing framework.

So my own response is: **for pytest fixtures, then use pytest instead of asynctest.**

For the logging issue, it can be solved by getting and mocking the logging function.

```py
    async def test_get_error_log(self):
        """ Simple test that assert logs emitted. """
        logging.error = asynctest.Mock()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        logging.error.assert_called_once_with(":(")
```